# PHP: How to get the last directory paths and echo them

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have my .htaccess and index.php files located inside "localhost/poppers/f/". I have all url request from "/f/" directory processed by index.php. What I want to get and echo is just the whole path after the "f" directory regardless of how many trailing slash it contains.

Example: **localhost/poppers/f/abcdef/123456/xyz/456**

Output I want is: **abcdef/123456/xyz/456** (regardless of the number of the following directories)

What I'm trying to use is: `dirname(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an environment variable in your rewrite rule and access it inside the PHP code:

Keep your `/poppers/f/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /poppers/f/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php [L,E=URIPART:$1]
```

This will route every request to `index.php` and set relative path from `/poppers/f/` as an env variable `URIPART`.

Now inside your `index.php` just get this value as:

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URIPART"]
```

which will show value: `abcdef/123456/xyz/456`

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "localhost/poppers/f/abcdef/123456/xyz/456";
$parts = explode('/', $string);
```

At this point you can simply remove the first two parts and implode() the rest...

```
echo implode( array_slice($parts,3), '/' );
```